# Error "type character varying is not composite" when sending query from SAS to Greenplum

Tags: postgresql, sas, greenplum

Good day!
When sending a query from SAS script to our Greenplum database, I sometimes get an error like this:

```
create table new as 
select contact_id 
from connection to gp 
(   select c6.contact_id 
    from PRD_T_CDM.contacts c6, PRD_T_CDM.offers o6 
    where c6.channel_cd = 'OB:SASMA_OFFER' and c6.status = 6 and c6.processed_DTTM between 
    to_timestamp('2023-04-04 02:46:49', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - interval '20' day and current_date 
    and c6.offer_id = o6.offer_id and exists 
    (   select 1 
        from PRD_T_CDM.contacts c5, PRD_T_CDM.offers o5 
        where c5.offer_id = o5.offer_id and 
        ( 
            ( c5.sappn = c6.sappn and o5.campaign_cd = o6.campaign_cd and trim(effort_product) != '778' ) 
            or 
            ( c5.offer_id = c6.offer_id and trim(effort_product) = '778' ) 
        ) 
        and c5.channel_cd = 'OB:SASMA_OFFER' and c5.status = 5 and c5.processed_DTTM 
        between to_timestamp('2023-04-04 02:46:49', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - interval '20' day and current_date 
    ) 
);
```

```
ERROR: CLI open cursor error: [SAS][ODBC Greenplum Wire Protocol driver][Greenplum]ERROR: type character varying is not composite  
       (seg0 slice2 10.84.168.188:10000 pid=13059)(File typcache.c; Line 758; Routine lookup_rowtype_tupdesc_internal; )
```

I did not create any composite types and can't track down what's causing the problem, I ran the request separately couple of times - everything is fine.

Comment: I don't know anything about GREENPLUM database but passing a quoted string to INTERVAL keyword seems strange to me.  Shouldn't it need a NUMBER to indicate the number of intervals to adjust by?  it would make more sense to me if the syntax wanted `interval 20 days` or `interval 20 'days'` instead of `interval '20' days`.

Comment: Hi, Tom! Thank you for your attentiveness, that may indeed be the problem. The original query was for a Teradata database that uses this format for an interval and apparently I didn't change it to the Postgres format (Greenplum is powered by Postgres). I'll check if this helps!

Comment: `INTERVAL '20 days'` is what you want - typename and value.